# Selecting groups in which all elements satisfy a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
trade_id   position_id   exit_date
34         1
35         1             2016-01-02
36         2             2016-02-07
37         2             2016-02-06
38         3           
39         3
```

I need to group by `position_id` and only select positions where every trade_id within that group has an `exit_date` filled in. In other words, every `trade_id` within each `position_id` group must have a `exit_date` in order to be selected.

In the above table, there is only one qualifying group, ie: position_id = 2

I have tried the following:

```
select position_id from trades
where exit_date is not null
group by position_id
```

But that selects positions even if only one of the trades has an exit_date filled in. I need to only have positions where all exit_dates have been filled in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `WHERE` you should use `HAVING` with a `COUNT`, like this:

```
SELECT position_id
FROM trades
GROUP BY position_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=COUNT(exit_date)
```

`COUNT(*)` counts all rows, while `COUNT(exit_date)` counts rows with non-`NULL` value in the `exit_date` column. Therefore, `HAVING` keeps only `position_id=2` for which both these counts are equal to each other.